# event.oldURL is undefined

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

On hashchange event the event.oldURL values comes as undefined in IE but works fine for other browser.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(event) {
    console.log("hash value:: " + event.oldURL);
});
```

Is there any other method to access the oldURL for IE because I am able to get the value in other browser.

Please correct me where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just tracks old url using any variable

Comment: Does IE support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(event) {
console.log("hash value:: "+event.originalEvent.oldURL );
});
```

Comment: You sure IE supports it?

Comment: My bad, sorry IE doesnotsupport oldURL. Is there any other alterative to get the oldURL value in IE.

Comment: @Dimal event.originalEvent.oldURL also gives undefined as the output.:)